# Неправильно отображаются товары в ряд

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Некорректно отображается каталог товаров в woocommerce. Товары отображаются на пол-страницы, точнее процентов на 75%, в настройках темы (тема Rife) включено отображение на всю ширину страницы.

В чем может быть проблема, возможно нужно что-то в стилях поменять?

Comment: Этот вопрос задавайте создателям темы, но никак не на SO

Comment: Прикрепите ссылку на сайт, скриншот с проблемой и все что может показать суть проблемы